# SQL Server : count pairs from two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I need for an application I'm building, but I'm struggling to find the best answer.

Suppose I have a table named `Messages`, with the following columns:

```
MessageID, From, To, Text
```

I want to count all messages between `From` and `To` such as that if the table looks like this:

```
ID From  To   Text
------------------
 1    a   b     hi
 2    b   a  hello
 3    a   c   test
```

So basically I want the result to look like

```
a, b, 2
a, c, 1
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

Similar answer to Gordon, posted about 20 seconds later, with one important difference.  ANSI SQL requires that no derived columns appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  I first use a CTE to compute the least and greatest of the to/from pairs, and then do an aggregation query on that CTE.  In this case, we end up grouping on actual, not derived, columns.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [From] <  [To] THEN [From] ELSE [To] END AS [From],
        CASE WHEN [From] >= [To] THEN [From] ELSE [To] END AS [To]
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    [From], [To], COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    [From], [To]
```

Note also that you should avoid using SQL keywords such as `From` to name your columns and tables.  To get this query to work, you absolutely would have to use the column as `[From]`, because without brackets SQL Server would confound it with the `FROM` keyword.

Comment: Works perfectly, appreciate your thorough explanation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Most databases have `least()` and `greatest()`, which make this easier.  In SQL Server, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when [from] < [to] then [from] else [to] end),
       (case when [from] < [to] then [to] else [from] end),
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when [from] < [to] then [from] else [to] end),
         (case when [from] < [to] then [to] else [from] end);
```

I would have named the columns, but I can't think of appropriate names.